# Sharpening corners in Firefox 8 & bringing back old "new tab" icon

Tags: firefox

I'm not a fan of rounded corners in the UI for most programs.  I'm wondering if anyone knows of some sort of extension, stylish script, or theme that sharpens the corners of the buttons in my Firefox toolbar to the old 3.6 style.

On top of that, the new Firefox 8 update changed the way the icon for a new tab looks.  Now it's this funky looking dotted square:

[image]

I preferred the old icon with the paper with a folded corner.  Any way to bring it back?

Comment: Use the old version of Firefox?

Comment: @techie007: ...no. Just no.

Comment: @grawity Hey, I didn't put it in as an answer! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit the [userChrome.css](http://kb.mozillazine.org/UserChrome.css) file to get the old "new tab" icon back:

```
/*
 * Do not remove the @namespace line -- it's required for correct functioning
 */
@namespace url("http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul"); /* set default namespace to XUL */

#page-proxy-favicon:not(src), .tab-icon-image:not(src),
#personal-bookmarks .bookmark-item .toolbarbutton-icon:not(src) {
list-style-image: url("chrome://global/skin/icons/folder-item.png")!important;
-moz-image-region: rect(0px, 16px, 16px, 0px)!important;
}
}
```

Comment: @Slim_K Awesome, works brilliantly.  Just another question - how about the icon for a bookmarked webpage in the Bookmarks menu that doesn't have a favicon?  When I open up the Bookmarks menu they're all also using that weird square outline.

Comment: @White - modified the answer. Now the bookmarks should show old icons as well.

Comment: @Slim_K Unfortunately, the modification you made only affected my Bookmarks toolbar.  If I open up the Bookmarks menu or use the "Show All Bookmarks" option to organize my bookmarks, the outline is still there.  I double checked to make sure I pasted the code correctly, and it seems to be correct.  Could there be some incorrect code here or a clashing extension?  Once again, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found a stylish theme that changes the mentioned icon to a Firefox logo, if you just do a little editing on the script you could make it any logo you wanted.

[Branding Logo as Favicon on New/Blank Tabs](http://userstyles.org/styles/52581/fx-7-branding-logo-as-favicon-on-new-blank-tabs)